# Does realm has some convenience method that can delete all the RLMObject which has the same property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

For example, there are a Dog and a Cat Object, and they all have the same property "owner", how can I delete all the dog and cat which have the same owner in the database? Do I have to delete them individually? It bothers me because I need to delete so many objects at a time based on a property they all have.

Comment: u can write a predicate and and get all the objects that has the same owner, and u can enumerate and delete them all.

Comment: Can you share with us an example model of your database? When you say "the same property" it can be for instance a `NSString` or a custom subclass of `RLMObject`, so we can't be sure on how to help you.

Comment: just `NSString` type

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way to achieve this. None of Realm's Collection types support having elements from different types, so you cannot create a Realm `List` or `Results` instance that could hold all your objects that share the same property, but have different types.

In the future once Realm outgrows this limitation, you should be able to define a superclass, called `Animal`, which have an `owner` property, make both `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from the `Animal` class, then delete all objects from `Realm` that inherit from `Animal`.

However, at the moment even if you make an abstract `Animal` class and make both `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from `Animal`, if you try to delete all objects of type `Animal` from `Realm`, it will only delete the objects whose type is actually `Animal`, but it won't delete any objects whose type inherits from `Animal`.

See [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1109) GitHub issue for details about the problem around inheritance in Realm and some workarounds.

Comment: While Realm Cocoa has some support for model inheritance, there are quite a few caveats.  The recommended approach is to use composition over inheritance .  https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let samsPets = realm.objects(Pet.self).filter("owner.name = 'Sam'")
do {
    try realm.write {
        realm.delete(samsPets)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Here we're querying for all pets, who's owners name is sam and deleting them.  This could be all done in one statement too.

This assumes that each pet has a property reference to their owner.
(i.e. `dynamic var owner: Person?`)

Comment: How does this solve the issue of deleting multiple classes at the same time? Your Pet class is only a single class.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  I just saw your answer, but it sounds like it can not solve my issue. In simple terms, I need to delete multiple classes at the same time as @DávidPásztor said.

Comment: You are correct, I miss understood the question initially. I thought you were looking to delete all objects of type Pet the had the same owner.  I see now, you're asking about model inheritance.  In this case @DávidPásztor answer is correct.  I added a comment to his answer which links to the part of the Realm docs that discusses the limits of Model Inheritance with Realm and recommendations.